# How to style ToggleButon in material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to style ToggleButton to override default color when it's selected. But it doesn't work.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({   
  toggleButtonSelected: {
      "background-color": "red"
  }
}))

.......
<ToggleButtonGroup exclusive>
    <ToggleButton
        classes={{ selected: classes.toggleButtonSelected }}
        value="a" >
        Button A
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
        classes={{ selected: classes.toggleButtonSelected }}
        value="b">
        Button B
    </ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Try to change your `makeStyles` styling to the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  toggleButtonSelected: {
    "&.MuiToggleButton-root": {
      "background-color": "red"
    }
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit on Code Sandbox]

## Explanation

[image: Original specificity]

Your original `makeStyles` styling is not working because it generates a CSS rule with selector of `.makeStyles-toggleButtonSelected-1` (circled in red in the above screenshot), which is overridden by another rule with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

With our new `makeStyles` styling, it generates a CSS rule with the selector having a higher selectivity than your original styling (circled in red in below). This new styling can successfully override the default styling.

[image: New specificity]